# Cannot nest bottomTabNavigator inside DrawerNavigator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to nest a bottomTabNavigator inside the DrawerNavigator using the React Navigation library but an error comes up telling me to use a React component or a Navigator to for the DrawerNavigator's route.

This is the `DrawerNavigator.js` file where i create the DrawerNavigator.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import SideBar from '../components/SideBar';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator';

export default createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MainTabNavigator,
    }
},{
    contentComponent: SideBar
})
```

This is the `MainTabNavigator.js` file where i create the bottomTabBarNavigator

```
const MainTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: HomeStack,
    MultiBar: {
        screen: () => null,
        navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
            tabBarIcon: () => (
                <CustomTabBarBottom />
            )
        }),
        params: {
            navigationDisabled: true
        }
    },
    Video: VideoStack

}, {
  tabBarComponent: props =>
    <TabBarComponent
      {...props}
    />,
    tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,

  },

});


export default MainTabNavigator;
```

Please look into this and tell me if i'm missing something, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my `AppNavigator.js` which is used as the main app container:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import AuthLoadingScreen from '../screens/AuthLoadingScreen';
import MainTabNavigator from './MainTabNavigator'
import AuthStackNavigator from './AuthStackNavigator';
import DrawerNavigator from './DrawerNavigator';
const MainAppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    AuthLoadingScreen: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: DrawerNavigator,
    Auth: AuthStackNavigator,
});

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(MainAppNavigator)
export default AppNavigator
```

By removing the `MainTabNavigator` import which i don't use at all in the file, the error goes away (which is really bizarre ).

Answer (score 0):

This is my code of bottomTabBar with Drawer. may this will help you.

Just add your **MainTabNavigation** as the first screen of your **createDrawerNavigator** in your code.

I have used react-navigation version 3.0

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import {
  createAppContainer,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator
} from "react-navigation";
import Heal from "./component/tabs/Heal";
import Submit from "./component/tabs/Submit";
import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from "react-navigation-tabs";
import ProfileSetting from "./component/drawerTabs/ProfileSetting";
import ChangePassword from "./component/drawerTabs/ChangePassword";
import Help from "./component/drawerTabs/Help";
import Logout from "./component/drawerTabs/Logout";
import Drawer from "./component/drawerTabs/Drawer";
import { FontTypes } from "./style/Font";
import { ColorCodes } from "./style/Color";

const TabBarComponent = props => <BottomTabBar {...props} />;
export const TabScreens = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    "Heal a case": { screen: Heal },
    "Submit a case": { screen: Submit }
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: props => (
      // <BottomTabView {...props}/>
      <TabBarComponent
        {...props}
        activeBackgroundColor={ColorCodes.primary}
        showIcon={false}
        allowFontScaling={true}
        activeTintColor="#fff"
        inactiveTintColor="#000"
        labelStyle={{ fontSize: 17, fontFamily: FontTypes.Roboto }}
        tabStyle={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          borderWidth: 0
        }}
        style={
          {
            // backgroundColor: "red"
          }
        }
      />
    )
  }

);



export const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    "My Cases": {
      screen: TabScreens
    },
    "Profile Setting": {
      screen: ProfileSetting
    },
    "Change Password": {
      screen: ChangePassword
    },
    Help: {
      screen: Help
    },
    Logout: {
      screen: Logout
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: Drawer,
    drawerBackgroundColor: "white",
    drawerType: "front",
    contentOptions: {
      labelStyle: {
        fontFamily: FontTypes.Roboto,
        color: ColorCodes.primary,

      },
      activeLabelStyle:{
        color:ColorCodes.iconColor
      }
    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator);
```

Comment: yes, i already did this, MainTabNavigator is the only screen i add in the createDrawerNavigator function but an error pops up: 
`The component for route "Home" must be a React component. For example:

import MyScreen from './Myscreen';
...
Home: Myscreen,
}

You can also use a navigator:
import MyNavigator from './MyNavigator;
...
Home: MyNavigator,
}'`

Comment: i also use react navigation 2 if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this still helps but I had the same problem and solved it by having all components in one file and moving the other navigators up, so that the createDrawerNavigator component is at the bottom of the file. 
This looks like hoisting does not work here? I am actually confused about this, but there you go.